# github api - create repo

Tags: api, github, repository

I'm trying to create a repo using Github API, but it always return this JSON:

```
{"message":"Not Found"}
```

But this error appears only when I try to create using OAuth access token in request header, if I use username and password, API create the repo and return a successful message.

Anyone had problems with this API endpoint?

Comment: could you solve it using post method? I get the same message

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new repository using the Python library, [PyGithub](http://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

```
from github import Github
g = Github("your username", "your password")
g = Github("your token")  # safer alternative, if you have an access token
u = g.get_user()
repo = u.create_repo("name-of-your-repo")
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a different message come up with this

```
curl -i -d '{"name":"NAME"}' https://api.github.com/orgs/:ORG/repos?access_token=XXX

{
  "message": "Must be an owner or admin of Organization."
}
```

But still not sure why I cannot create either

Ok

This worked for me

Create Auth Token

```
curl -u 'iwarner' -d '{"scopes":["repo"],"note":":NAME"}' https://api.github.com/authorizations
```

Create Repo - Need to contain "Authorization: token"

```
curl -i -H 'Authorization: token TOKENHERE' -d '{"name":":NAME"}' https://api.github.com/user/repos
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, just tried it.

```
curl -F 'login=c00kiemon5ter' -F 'token=s3cr3t' https://github.com/api/v2/json/repos/create -F 'name=testapi' -F 'public=0'
```

Are we talking about API *v2* or *v3* ?

Comment: Sorry, forget to mention. I'm trying to create using v3 api.

I'm using the same command showed in api docs, but with my OAuth Token (if I use the token to watch a repo, it works).

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what technology you are using. But just in case of iOS, you can use this demo app which describes 3 simple ways to interact with the GitHub API.

Note: This demo app provide only few selected functionality.

[GitHub-Interaction](https://github.com/verma-manish58/GitHub-Interaction)

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

As of today, the [GitHub v3 API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create) explicitly states:

> ### Create
>
> Create a new repository for the authenticated user. **(Currently not enabled for Integrations)**

**EDIT:**
<strike>The "not enabled for Integrations" means, if you get your OAuth token via [one of your OAuth apps](https://github.com/settings/developers) (which is an "integration") the GitHub API will refuse to create a repository with that function.</strike>

However, if you use some other access token (e.g. a [personal access token](https://github.com/settings/tokens) you add yourself, see below) then the GitHub API will happily create a repository for you with the very same API call.

```
curl -u your_username -d '{"scopes":["repo"], "note":"Description of personal token"}' https://api.github.com/authorizations
```

That's the reason why the solution presented by Ian Warner works. The solution with PyGithub will suffer the same limitation. **Only the token makes the difference!**

**EDIT:** Not entirely true: With OAuth you can **specify the [scope](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#scopes)** to **attach specific permissions** to your OAuth token when authenticating (OAuth app flow). For creating repositories you need to have the `'repo'` scope. (See also: [Github v3 API - create a REPO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870680/github-v3-api-create-a-repo))