# Github Api v3 giving 404 when I try to create a repo

Tags: api, github

I've executed the following command with the respective response.
However, if I try to get information about the `/user`, it works, witch means that my token is valid.

What Am I doing wrong?

```
guto@willie:~/$ curl -v -XPOST -H 'Authorization: token S3CR3T' -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'  https://api.github.com/user/repos -d '{"name":"my-new-repo","description":"my new repo description"}'
```

Output:

```
* About to connect() to api.github.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 207.97.227.243... connected
* Connected to api.github.com (207.97.227.243) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: O=*.github.com; OU=Domain Control Validated; CN=*.github.com
*    start date: 2009-12-11 05:02:36 GMT
*    expire date: 2014-12-11 05:02:36 GMT
*    subjectAltName: api.github.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; ST=Arizona; L=Scottsdale; O=GoDaddy.com, Inc.; OU=http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository; CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority; serialNumber=07969287
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /user/repos HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.3 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.3 OpenSSL/0.9.8o zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.18
> Host: api.github.com
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: token S3CR3T
> Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
> Content-Length: 62
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Server: nginx/1.0.4
< Date: Tue, 27 Dec 2011 03:45:12 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Connection: keep-alive
< Status: 404 Not Found
< X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
< ETag: "31b00b4920d3470b70611b10e0ba62a7"
< X-OAuth-Scopes: public_repo, user
< X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4976
< X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: repo
< Content-Length: 29
< 
{
  "message": "Not Found"
}
* Connection #0 to host api.github.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
guto@willie:~/projetos/apostilas/4linux-helper$
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the [Oath Scope GitHub documentation](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/):

```
$ curl -H "Authorization: bearer TOKEN" https://api.github.com/users/technoweenie -I
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-OAuth-Scopes: repo, user
X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes: user
```

You need to have the **`repo`** scope in order to have the right to create a repo, as illustrated by the SO question "[Github v3 API - create a REPO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870680/github-v3-api-create-a-repo)".

```
repo
```

> DB read/write access, and Git read access to public and private repos.
>
> NOTE: Your application can request the scopes in the initial redirection.
>   You can specify multiple scopes by separating them by a comma.

```
https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?
  client_id=...&
  scope=user,public_repo
```

Comment: I know, but if you take a look on the headers that the service returns. I'm already registered on those scopes: < X-OAuth-Scopes: public_repo, user

Comment: @gutomaia: true, the only difference is '`repo`' instead of '`public_repo`', but I suppose you have an account valid only for managing public repo (and not private ones). The only other explanation is some type/wrong parameter somewhere.

Comment: Unfortunelly, there is nothing wrong with the parameters. If I use a invalid token access, the service gives a unauthorized error. I really don't know why. Method name is okay, params is okay, token is okay even the content-type is okay. What else?!

Comment: @gutomaia: did you try it for other repos. Or ask other collaborators to try the same kind of command on their own repos?

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
curl -v -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d '{"name":"my-new-repo","description":"my new repo description"}' https://api.github.com/user/repos?access_token=S3CR3T
```