# fatal: repository 'https://github.com/user_name/first_app.git/' not found

Tags: git, version-control, github, repository

I was trying to push my files on the `github` but I am receiving this error. None of what they call a username works unfortunately ! Any thought?

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:first_app mona$ git push -u origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': lamiastella
Password for 'https://lamiastella@github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/lamiastella/first_app.git/' not found
Monas-MacBook-Pro:first_app mona$ git push -u origin master
Username for 'https://github.com': jalal@wisc.edu
Password for 'https://jalal@wisc.edu@github.com': 
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/lamiastella/first_app.git/' not found
```

Here's the list of commands I used before this command:

```
521  git init
522  git add .
523  git status
524  git commit -m "hi"
525  git status
526  git log
527  git checkout -f
528  git status
531  git remote add origin https://github.com/lamiastella/first_app.git
```

Comment: @zerkms Just search "git push" here  http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book#code-gemfile_sqlite_version I was following this manual but I am not sure what I am missing

Comment: you're missing the fact that you're adding a **NOT EXISTING** repository as `origin`. Read the paragraph before `git push` part in the article once again: "After signing up, **click on the link to create a repository** and fill in the information as in Figure 1.6. "

Comment: @zerkms Ah thanks so much. I forgot to create a repository in github site. However is there any terminal command for creating a repo say named first_app?

Comment: there is a GitHub API endpoint for creating repositories: http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#create So presumably there are some tools that could use it, but I haven't ever thought of that (creating repository is a rare process that would still require you to use github.com to set it up properly)

Comment: It's also possible you don't have "push" rights to that repo yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to script the all process, including the creation of a new repo, you can have a look at "[Github v3 API - create a REPO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7871165/6309)" or [this gist](https://gist.github.com/miohtama/4062655):

```
# Test drive on a single liner
# TOKEN="xxxx" org="plone-gomobile" p=test ; curl -v -XPOST -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" https://api.github.com/orgs/$org/repos -d '{"name": "'"$p"'"}'
curl -v -XPOST -H "Authorization: token $TOKEN" https://api.github.com/orgs/$org/repos -d '{"name": "'"$p"'"}'
```

Read more at "[Authentication](http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication)", and note that [OAuth2 tokens](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) can be [acquired programmatically](http://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#create-a-new-authorization), which can be helpful for your script.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered this same issue. In my case the problem was not with me, it was because Github is having problems with their SSH access, as it says on their status page (https://status.github.com/)

> "We are investigating problems with repository access and some GitHub.com features. We will report back once we have more information to share."