# Creating git repositories by a new git username and password

Tags: github

My requirement is that I have to create a git repository through git api. This is achievable with the accounts which are present in github.

But my case is that whenever i have to create a git repository it should be created with a new github username and password. This account I need to create first n github and the I need to create repo with the help of these account.

Can someone suggest me how to create github username and password through github api. I am looking for this but seems for this api is not present.

Comment: Please clearly keep "git" and "GitHub" as separate concepts. git repositories are created by `git init`. GitHub repositories can be created using GitHub API. git has no concept of a user, unless you use remotes (and has no way of creating users on remotes). GitHub users can be created on the GitHub page (possibly using Mechanize; not sure if that would be allowed or not, you should read GitHub terms of service), but not by GitHub API.

Comment: @Amadan - I have to create a git repository through an API call. can you pls help me out on this ?

Comment: Please reread what I said. git does not have an API beyond `git init`. GitHub does have [API](https://developer.github.com/v3/): [how to create repository using GitHub API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7870680/github-v3-api-create-a-repo).

Answer (score 0):

I think a valid answer here is that "it can't be done".
You can't create new users through the Git api, that will need to be manual as you need email addresses to be associated with each new account.

One you have an account you want to use though, you can do config/creation through new accounts with their [first time setup guide](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup).